# How to use a Spring Bean accross different classes

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I'm getting problems when I try to print out database items via the `SimpleJdbcDaoSupport` `getJdbcTemplate()` from accross different classes, class `SomeOtherClass` in this case.

My implementation is like so:

main class:

```
public class JdbcDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        HibernateDaoImpl dao = ctx.getBean("hibernateDaoImpl", HibernateDaoImpl.class);
        System.out.println(dao.getCircleCount());
        new TestController().printDb();
    }
}
```

some other class `SomeOtherClass`:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJdbcDaoImpl simpleJdbcDaoImpl;

    public void printDb() {
        System.out.println(simpleJdbcDaoImpl.getCircleCount() + " : trial here.....");
    }
}
```

`System.out.println(dao.getCircleCount());` in class `JdbcDemo` works fine, but not `new TestController().printDb();` in `SomeOtherClass`. Why is that so?

The stack-trace:

```
8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rev.TestController.printDb(TestController.java:12)
    at com.rev.JdbcDemo.main(JdbcDemo.java:17)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 35 seconds)
```

`8` is the output from `System.out.println(dao.getCircleCount());`

Where I extend `SimpleJdbcDaoSupport`

```
public class SimpleJdbcDaoImpl extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport {

    public int getCircleCount() {
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CIRCLE";
        return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql);
    }
}
```

I will greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

UPDATE:

The spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:D:\\WAKILI\\jdbcdemodb"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleJdbcDaoImpl" class="com.rev.dao.SimpleJdbcDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rev.model" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rev"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: plz post ur `spring.xml` as well

Comment: The problem is you're instantiating `TestController` yourself (according to your description), which means you are assuming responsibility for its dependencies. If you let Spring manage an instance of `TestController` as a bean, then it will instantiate it and inject the dependencies for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pat. I just added the spring.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can only fill injected/autowired resources if the enclosing class is itself a spring managed bean.

You have to:

- annotate SomeOtherClass with `@Service`
- fetch that class from spring context by `ctx.getBean(SomeOtherClass.class).printDb();`

Answer (score 0):

is your SomeOtherClass  is also spring bean? It has to be if you are injecting resource in it.